# RShiny, shinymanager, RSQLite, Heroku deployment

Tags: authentication, heroku, shiny

My app is working perfectly on my Desktop, but I forgot that heroku does not play well with SQLite.

So when I am building the app I am getting an error when it is installing shinymanager as this library needs the RSQLite library to be installed and this RSQLite library cannot be installed for the reason above.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: If shinymanager _requires_ SQLite, you're out of luck. Find another library. If it can be configured to use a client-server database backend, configure it to do that.

Comment: I will rewrite it with Postgres omg it will take so much time !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using heroku-buildpack-r, then the issue is between this buildpack and shinymanager. See this thread about it:
https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/issues/142

One solution mentioned here is to use a replacement buildpack, namely, heroku-docker-r